# What functions can be represented as a series of eigenfunctions

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series, eigenfunctions

Consider the differential equation:

$y'' = \lambda y$

with the boundary conditions
$y(0) = y(2\pi) = 0$.

This equation has eigenfunctions $\mu_n(x) = \sin(\frac{nx}{2})$ with the corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_n = -\frac{n^2}{4}$ for $n > 0$

- Am I right, that **certain** functions f(x) satisfying the same boundary conditions as above can be represented as an infinite series
  $f(x) = \sum_1^\infty c_n \mu_n(x)$ with coefficients $c_n = \frac{\langle f,\mu_n \rangle}{\langle \mu_n, \mu_n \rangle}$? **What** conditions those certain functions need to satisfy?
- Can the previous claim be generalised for any set of eigenfunctions of some differential equation? I.E. suppose $Ly = \lambda y$ is a differential equation ($L$ being the 2nd order differential operator) with boundary conditions $y(a) = y(b) = c$ . What functions can be represented as a weighted sum of the eigensolutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question situates within the realm of [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) and my subsequent answer applies to all differential operators (with associated eigenfunctions) that belong to this realm. You asked which continuous functions can be expanded in a series of eigenfunctions? The most natural answer turns out to be "functions that are square-integrable on the interval $(0,2\pi)$". Also non-continuous, square-integrable functions $f$ can be expanded in this way (under the proviso that $f$ is allowed to differ from its series-expansion $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\langle \mu_n,f\rangle}{\langle \mu_n,\mu_n\rangle} \mu_n(x)$ on a subset of $(0,2\pi)$ of measure zero)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following problem on the interval $[a,b]$ for some $a < b$ and real angles $\alpha,\beta$:
$$
            y''=\lambda y,\;\;\; a \le x \le b, \\
      \cos\alpha y(a)+\sin\alpha y'(a) = 0 \\
      \cos\beta y(b)+\sin\beta y'(b) = 0
$$
This gives rise to a discrete set of eigenvalues
$$
      \lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3 < \cdots,
$$

and associated eigenfunctions $\phi_n(x)$. For any function $f\in L^2[a,b]$, the Fourier series for $f$ in these eigenfunctions converges to $f$ in $L^2[a,b]$. And you get pointwise convergence of the series at $x\in(a,b)$ under the same type of Fourier conditions that you learned for the ordinary Fourier series. The endpoint conditions make the convergence at $x=a,b$ trickier, of course. Conditions of the type $y(a)=0=y(b)$, for example, forces any series in these eigenfunctions to converge to $0$ at the endpoints.

Comment: I liked these endpoint considerations. That is a very nice introduction to the fact that pointwise Fourier convergence *must* be trickier than the L^2 one.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand all continuous functions, and even the non-continuous ones (but they must be square-integrable); however, the series will only converge in the $L^2(0, 1)$ sense. This means that, defining 
$$
Sf_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n c_n \mu_n, $$
it holds that 
$$
\int_0^1 |Sf_n(x)-f(x)|^2\, dx\to 0\qquad \text{as }n\to \infty.$$

If you want *pointwise* convergence, you will need some regularity assumptions on $f$. This is a classical problem in Fourier analysis.